# Fontspec shifts some diacritics marks when LetterSpacing

Tags: fontspec, unicode, accents, letterspacing

[image]The fontspec feature LetterSpacing does not give the same result with a letter typed in ASCII form (e.g. \^E ) that when it is typed in UTF-8 form (e.g. Ê). The log file of the joined ECM shows that it seems that Fontspec uses the canonical form ( E+Combining Circumflex Accent AND A+Combining Grave Accent ) instead of Ê and À and does not set the corresponding accent on its correct position. This results as shifted accents in the output. Futhermore an extra \glue(\spaceskip) is added before and after À in the text.

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmainfont{Erewhon}
%\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagella}

\newcommand{\Ascii}{ARR\^ET B\^ETE \`A LU\c CON CET \'ET\'E.\\
 \`A \'A \^A \"A \`E \'E \^E \"E \`I \'I \^I \"I \`O \'O \^O \"O \`U \'U \^U \"U
}

\newcommand{\Unicode}{ARRÊT BE\char"0302TE À LUÇON CET ÉTÉ.\\
                      À Á Â Ä È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ò Ó Ô Ö Ù Ú Û Ü E\char"302}

\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\showoutput

\Ascii

\Unicode

----------------- LetterSpace=20/100 (0.2pt)
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20}

\Ascii

\Unicode

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% coding: utf-8-unix
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% End:
```

Comment: the handling of accent commands is declared in tuenc.def - you seem to have an older version, in a current system `\^E` maps to Ê. For the letterspacing I opened an issue here https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/127.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: what puzzles me is why input Unicode characters À and Ê are split into (base char + combining accent) while É is output as É in Jacques' MWE.  Even stranger, as single accented characters (last line) they are not converted into (base char + combining accent) with letterspacing on.

Comment: @DanielFlipo I get no split neither with xelatex nor with lualatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I do with LuaLaTeX 1.10 from TL2019 updated today. With XeLaTeX on the same machine it works as expected (no split). What am I missing?

Comment: @DanielFlipo I think I compiled with lualatex-dev and my development version of luaotfload. I will try with the default later.

Comment: @DanielFlipo I don't see the effect, and I also don't think that luaotfload ever had code which would lead to character decomposition. Are you sure that the input has a composed glyph? Which OS do you use?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am on Debian Buster running TL2019 updated today. I have added the output of Jacques' file on my system. Ascii input (\^E \`A) works as expected but Unicode input (Ê, À) is split (É is not) when letterspacing is on: see the last two lines.  Looking at the .log file confirms the split thanks to \showoutput. Strange indeed!

Comment: @DanielFlipo put the tex-file and the log somewhere for download or sent it to me by mail.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry for the noise :-( You are right both problematic characters Ê and È looked like Unicode single characters but were indeed composed characters. I don't know how I managed to mess them up :-( Anyway thanks for your help, I do apologize for wasting your time!